# Select field validation

Tags: validation, laravel-8, laravel-validation, error-messaging

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="category-id">Category</label>
   <select id="category-id" class="form-control {{$errors->get('category_id') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}}" name="category_id">
      <option value="177">Select a category</option>
      @foreach ($categories as $category)
      <option value="{{$category['id']}}">{{$category['title']}}</option>
      @endforeach
   </select>
   @if ($errors->has('category_id'))
      <div class="invalid-feedback"><strong>{{$errors->first('category_id')}}</strong></div>
   @endif
</div>
```

The category_id is defined as the required field in my Request php file (`'category_id' => 'required'`)

But when I submit the form without any input to any field, all fields generate error messages by highlighting the field, except this **SELECT** field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It passes the validation because your are sending a value in that field.

Change this

```
<option value="177">Select a category</option>
```

to

```
<option selected disabled>Select a category</option>
```

then it should not pass the validation.